# QTRLE is supported by ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

- I am trying to create video using QTRLE format with RGB24 or ARGB pixel format in ffmpeg library.But video is not played.
- But is i use H264 format with yuv format then it's working fine.
- Is QTRLE is not supported by ffmpeg or i m doing any mistake?

  ```
  static void video_encode_example(const char *filename, int codec_id)
  {
          AVCodec *codec;
          AVCodecContext *c = NULL;
          int i, ret, x, y, got_output;
          FILE *f;
          AVFrame *frame;
          AVPacket pkt;
          uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };

          printf("Encode video file %s\n", filename);

          /* find the mpeg1 video encoder */

          codec = avcodec_find_encoder((AVCodecID) codec_id);
          //  codec = 28;
          if (!codec) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Codec not found : %d\n", codec_id);
              exit(1);
          }

          c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);

          if (!c) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
              exit(1);
          }

          /* put sample parameters */
          c->bit_rate = 400000;
          /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
          c->width = 352;
          c->height = 288;
          /* frames per second */
          c->time_base = (AVRational ) { 1, 25 };
          /* emit one intra frame every ten frames
           * check frame pict_type before passing frame
           * to encoder, if frame->pict_type is AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I
           * then gop_size is ignored and the output of encoder
           * will always be I frame irrespective to gop_size
           */
          c->gop_size = 10;
          c->max_b_frames = 1;
          c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;

          if (codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
              av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);

          /* open it */
          if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
              exit(1);
          }

          f = fopen(filename, "wb");
          if (!f) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
              exit(1);
          }

          frame = av_frame_alloc();
          if (!frame) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
              exit(1);
          }
          frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
          frame->width = c->width;
          frame->height = c->height;

          /* the image can be allocated by any means and av_image_alloc() is
           * just the most convenient way if av_malloc() is to be used */
          ret = av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, c->width, c->height,
                  c->pix_fmt, 32);
          if (ret < 0) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate raw picture buffer\n");
              exit(1);
          }
          ////////////////////////////////////
          cv::Mat input = imread("image for creating video(image.png)");
          Mat output;
          resize(input, input, Size(c->width, c->height));
          cvtColor(input, input, CV_BGR2RGB);

          av_image_fill_arrays(frame->data, frame->linesize, input.data,
                  c->pix_fmt, c->width, c->height, 1);

          ////////////////////////////////////

          for (i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
              av_init_packet(&pkt);
              pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
              pkt.size = 0;

              fflush(stdout);

              frame->pts = i;

              /* encode the image */
              ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
              if (ret < 0) {
                  fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
                  exit(1);
              }

              if (got_output) {
                  printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, pkt.size);
                  fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, f);
                  av_packet_unref(&pkt);
              }
          }

          /* get the delayed frames */
          for (got_output = 1; got_output; i++) {
              fflush(stdout);

              ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, NULL, &got_output);
              if (ret < 0) {
                  fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
                  exit(1);
              }

              if (got_output) {
                  printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, pkt.size);
                  fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, f);
                  av_packet_unref(&pkt);
              }
          }

          /* add sequence end code to have a real mpeg file */
          fwrite(endcode, 1, sizeof(endcode), f);
          fclose(f);

          avcodec_close(c);
          av_free(c);
      //  av_freep(&frame->data[0]);
          av_frame_free(&frame);
          printf("\n");
  }

  int main() {
      av_register_all();
      video_encode_example("test.mov", AV_CODEC_ID_QTRLE);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg supports QTRLE, the problem is you're looking at the wrong example.

The code you provided seems to be based on `decoding_encoding.c` which is an example of `libavcodec` usage that works on codecs *only*. It only outputs raw `h264` or `mpg`.

If you want to create a `mov` file you must mux the result in this format using `libavformat`. See the `muxing.c` example instead.

Comment: so if i want to generate video using qtrle with pixel format ARGB, then it is only possible with libavformat?

Comment: @Sagar `QTRLE` is a **codec** and to encode you use `libavcodec`. The result is an encoded video stream. `mov` is a container **format**. It can contain one or more streams. If you want to put your encoded video stream in a `mov` file you must use **libavformat**. [Read this](http://www.encoding.com/blog/2014/01/13/whats-difference-codecs-containers/).

Comment: but how can i do that.I have refered muxing.c file.But unable to understood.And it is not necessary to generate only mov file.mp4 is also fine.

Comment: @Sagar No matter what container format you choose you still need to use `libavformat` and mux.

Comment: but how to use it.I am unable to understood it.

Comment: @Sagar analyze the example step by step and it'll make sense. If not, maybe you could use FFmpeg via the command-line interface instead. If you get stuck on something specific post another question. Good luck!